# Rename files based on their ranked number?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm very new to scripting (bash shell) and I'm unable to figure out the logic of this task I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a folder with file names like these (for example):

```
PIC-100
PIC-1
PIC-23
PIC-5
```

I'd like to be able to take the number from their file name, rank them in order from lowest to highest, then rename it based on their position on the ranked list.

So for example, they'll be renamed like:

```
PIC-100 --> PIC-4
PIC-1   --> PIC-1
PIC-23  --> PIC-3
PIC-5   --> PIC-2
```

Thanks all.

Comment: "but be able to keep the same order as they were in the folder (i.e. they won't be sorted)" ... I don't understand this - entries in a directory aren't sorted. The application showing the entries might decide to sort them in some order, but then that depends entirely on the application.

Comment: I may have overexplained myself there. You're right that it is dependent on the application that they could be sorted in some way. What I meant to say is that I would like to keep them in the order they were loaded in. Sorry for the confusion, I'll removed that portion in the question.

Comment: Loaded into what? An array? Do you already have a script that you're looking to modify or add to?

Comment: What I meat by loaded into was the way they were inputted into the folder. At the moment, I'm having trouble working the logic of what I'd like to do so I don't currently have anything for a script.

Comment: I think this is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to preserve that order? What uses that order? Do you actually want to preserver modification times or something?

Comment: Sorry for a lot of the confusion. In this case, I think I'd just like to simplify my question. I don't need to preserve the order at all, I think I'm just making it much harder on myself and my task. EDIT: I edited the question to actually tackle on what I'd actually like to do vs. unimportant restrictions I had previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you how I'd approach this problem bit by bit. First, let's create some test data:

```
mkdir /tmp/blah && cd /tmp/blah
for f in 1 90 $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM; do touch PIC-$f; done
ls
```

The files should be shown sorted by name, but we want them sorted numerically. The command `sort` can help with this:

```
ls | sort -V
```

`-V` means "Versioned sort", which is fine for your case. For other options, see `man sort`.

Now for the rename. There's a bunch of ways to do this, but I'll loop over the output of our sorted list. We'll need a variable and a loop:

```
counter=1 ls PIC-* | sort -V | while read fname; do
    echo mv -i "$fname" NEWPIC-$counter
    let counter+=1
done
```

A lot is happening here, so I'll explain in some detail - starting with safety. First of all, **BACK UP YOUR FILES** before going any further - loops can go wrong very easily and cause a bad day. Here's a command to back everything up:

```
mkdir backup; cp PIC* backup
```

If we get this loop wrong we could make a mess, so I like to see what's going to happen before I run it. Notice the `echo`? This will print out the intended commands instead of running them. You can either remove the `echo` or just copy-paste the output to run the command "for real"

Next, I've run `mv -i` for the rename. This will prompt if I'm going to overwrite something - at that point everything has gone pear shaped anyway, but at least I'll know.

Third, notice that I'm renaming from `PIC-xxx` to `NEWPIC-xxx`. This is *really important* because I could accidentally rename PIC-3 over PIC-2 in certain cases (e.g. if there is a PIC-2.5 for some reason). We can clean up the `NEW` part later.

Also, I start the command with `counter=1 ls | sort -V | ...`. By setting the variable *in* the command, I avoid seeing "strange" behaviour when I forget to set it between test runs - where the destination filenames would start at `NEWPIC-6` or something instead of `NEWPIC-1`. This is one of those habits you pick up after making the mistake a few times :)

Now for the loop itself.

- `while read fname` says "every time you see a line of input, put the line into a variable `fname` and run the next part
- `do .. done` surrounds the code you want to run for each line
- `echo mv -i "$fname" NEWPIC-$counter` prints out the command you want to run
- `let counter+=1` increments your counter variable. If you forget this, you would end up with one file called `NEWPIC-1` and all your other files would be gone. This is why we have backups :)

Lastly, here's a little trick to remove that `NEW` from the start of the file name:

```
for fname in NEWPIC-*; do echo mv $fname ${fname#NEW}; done
```

As before, remove the `echo` when you are happy with the output.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer and detailed explanation! Great tips as well

Comment: This seems to assume that there are no other files in the current directory, and will rename _all_ files into `NEWPIC-n` (where `n` is an integer, except for the first one, where it's empty, because...). You also set `counter` uselessly in the environment of `ls` to `1` (this means that the first file will be called `NEWPIC-` with no number). You should use `counter=1; ls ...` to fix this. Any file whose name starts with a dash may upset the `mv` command. You should do `mv -i -- "$fname" ...` to fix this. Old files called `NEWPIC-n` may be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Kusalananda, I have updated the post

Answer (score 1):

This annotated shell script could do what you might want. The semicolons means execute commands sequentially, the vertical bars means pipeline, the hash sign starts comments, the "do-done" pair is the loop enclosed in "while"

```bsh
n=1            ; # initialize counter
ls             | # list current working directory
sort -V        | # sort (thanks to dwurf for the flag, but this isn't in POSIX standard yet)
while read f   ; do
mv "$f" PIC-$n ; # rename file 
n=$((n+1))     ; # counter increment. 
done
```

Comment: A couple of bugs: this will create files named `PIC-PIC-1` given the existing files already start with `PIC-`. The `sort -n` also won't work because the filenames don't start with numbers.

Comment: Noted, this is inferior to your answer, shame on me...

Comment: I noted the -n and -V flags, but double-prefix PIC-PIC wouldn't happen because I didn't name the second argument to `mv` as `"$f-$n"`. Also, after sorting, source ranking index would always be no less than the target naming index if my maths are correct.

Comment: Great answer! I was researching on ```sort``` and could sort work if we specify it like this: ```sort -n -t- -k2```, since all my files are named like ```PIC-[number]```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `zsh` shell:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

n=1
for name in PIC-*(.n); do
    mv $name $tmpdir/PIC-$(( n++ ))
done

mv $tmpdir/PIC-* .
rmdir $tmpdir
```

This moves+renames all regular files whose names matches `PIC-*` in the current directory into a temporary directory.  The files are moved in sorted numerical order based on the number in the filename (this is what the `n` in the `(.n)` glob qualifier does; the `.` selects only regular files).  For each file, the file is renamed into `PIC-n` where `n` is a counter.

Once all files have been moved and renamed, they are moved back into the current directory and the temporary directory is deleted.

The use of a temporary directory as a staging area is to avoid name collisions.

If there are several thousands of files, then the second `mv` may need to be executed in a loop instead to avoid an "argument list too long" error:

```
# first loop as before, then...

for name in $tmpdir/PIC-*; do
    mv $name .
done

rmdir $tmpdir
```

---

Doing the operations in "reverse order" will additionally give you a backup of the files with their original names in the temporary directory if you `cp` the file instead of `mv` them at the end:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

mv PIC-*(.) $tmpdir

n=1
for name in $tmpdir/PIC-*(n); do
    # change "mv" to "cp" (and remove "rmdir" below)
    # to leave a copy in the temporary directory
    mv $name PIC-$(( n++ ))
done

rmdir $tmpdir
```

Comment: The question had been (explicitly?) tagged with "bash", but zsh features such as ones used here may be applicable to bash since I'm not familiar with many "non-POSIX" features.

Comment: @DannyNiu The question was tagged with [tag:bash], but since a `bash` solution would use a number of external tools, such as `sort` and `ls`, you might as well use the `zsh` utility, which has much of the functionality built-in. It's not different from making use of e.g. `awk`.  I'm also noting that the question itself does not contain any code, so there's no `bash` script to look at, comment on, or correct.